# Spring Batch Processor Exception Listener?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a partitioned Spring Batch job that reads several split up CSV files and processes each in their own thread, then writes the results to a corresponding output file.

If an item fails to process though (an exception is thrown), I want to write that result to an error file. Is there a way to add a writer or listener that can handle this?

Taking this one step further, is there a way to split this up by exception type and write the different exceptions to different files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by specifying `SkipPolicy`. Implement this interface and add your own logic.

```
public class MySkipper implements SkipPolicy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable exception, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {

       if (exception instanceof XYZException) {
            //doSomething
       }
         ......
  }
```

You can specify this skip policy in your batch.

```
this.stepBuilders.get("importStep").<X, Y>chunk(10)
        .reader(this.getItemReader()).faultTolerant().skipPolicy(....)
        .processor(this.getItemProcessor())
        .writer(this.getItemWriter())
        .build();
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work and used Logback to write out entries to my file. I guess I could have also just done that in the Processor, but this seems a little more elegant.

Comment: What's the difference between SkipListener and SkipPolicy ?

Answer (score 2):

One way that I have seen this done is through a combination of a `SkipPolicy` and a `SkipListener`.

The policy would allow you to skip over items that threw an exception, such as a `FlatFileParseException` (skippable exceptions can be configured).

The listener gives you access to the `Throwable` and the item that caused it (or just Throwable in the case of reads).  The skip listener also lets you differentiate between skips in the read/processor/writer if you wanted to handle those separately.

```
public class ErrorWritingSkipListener<T, S> implements SkipListener<T, S> {

  @Override
  public void onSkipInRead(final Throwable t) {
     // custom logic
  }

  @Override
  public void onSkipInProcess(final T itemThatFailed, final Throwable t) {
      // custom logic
  }

  @Override
  public void onSkipInWrite(final S itemThatFailed, final Throwable t) {
    // custom logic
  }

}
```

I would recommend using the `SkipPolicy` only to identify the exceptions you want to write out to your various files, and leveraging the `SkipListener` to perform the actual file writing logic. That would match up nicely with their intended use as defined by their interfaces.

Comment: After a lot of googling, I found mentions of this, but I couldn't find any examples, and everything I found seems to expect chunks instead of partitions. After arriving at my Logback solution, everything got a lot simpler and I realized I really didn't need either of these, but am keeping the SkipPolicy in. Thanks for the suggestion!